# $this is not defined jQuery short script. The ajax works fine however

Tags: jquery

I have a short script which deletes a file. I want to then remove the closest div to the button. The ajax works fine however I am getting an error $this is not defined. Appreciate any help, I'm sure it's something obvious I'm doing.

```
/* Delete File*/
    $('.delete-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filename = $(this).attr('data-file');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax-delete.php',
            data: {'filename': filename},
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 'success'){
                    $this = $('#trf').closest();
                    $this.remove()
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have multiple `delete-btn`,  store a reference to the button instance parent before you make the ajax request . Then remove that stored element in the ajax success

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var filename = $(this).attr('data-file');

    var $parent = $(this).closest('div')// not sure if div also has a class

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax-delete.php',
        data: {'filename': filename},
        success: function(data){
            if (data == 'success'){
                $parent.remove()
                // remove element stored above
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the selector you want to find the `closest()` of

```
  if (data == 'success') $('#trf').closest('div').remove();
```

This was a direct response to your code structure, but @charlietfi's answer is more contextually right. A delete button that references a `closest()` element will almost always want to use `$(this)` as the base for the `closest()`.